# EmberJS URL format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ember.js

In EmberJS you can build a URL route as?:

http://www.mydomain.com/section/detail-123.html
123 is a variable

in angularJS the separators in URLs must be slash, I think also in Ember

Is there a framework of this kind that can do this kind of URLs?

Comment: I have never done this before, but I feel like it should be possible by customizing a Router (see http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/).  One noteworthy thing is that Ember routing (i.e. URL pathing) occurs after a # (hash) in your url.  With the # being the root of your ember app.  So if ember is loaded off of the /section path you'd end up with something like http://www.mydomain.com/section#detail-123.html.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ember one can achieve this kind of urls by combining the possibilities provided by the `serialize` hook of `Route` class (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize) to modify the url as required and `Ember.Location` (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Location.html) to remove the hash tag and enable only slashes in the url.

Example,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jenabegi/1/

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jenabegi/1/edit

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  /*the /jenabegi/1 part is added to make it function in jsbin*/
  this.route('index', {path: '/jenabegi/1/' });
  this.route("detail",{path:"/jenabegi/1/section/:detail_id"});
});
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect:function(){this.transitionTo("detail",{value:"123"});}
});

App.DetailRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  serialize:function(model,params){
    return {"detail_id":"detail-"+model.value+".html"};
  }
});
```